# FormView doesnt enter in insert mode. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, formview

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnModeChanging="FormView1_ModeChanging">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            ID :
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            CpuName :
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            Status :
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            There is no data.
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
     <table>
      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>ID: </b></td>       
        <td><%# Eval("Id") %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>CPUName:</b></td>     
        <td><%# Eval("cpuname") %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Status</b></td>      
        <td><%# Eval("status") %></td>
      </tr>

    </table>        
    <asp:LinkButton CommandName="Edit" runat="server">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton CommandName="Insert" runat="server">Insert</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
     <table>
      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>ID: </b></td>       
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFVID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>CPUName:</b></td>     
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFVName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Status</b></td>      
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFVStatus" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
      </tr>

    </table>        

    </InsertItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>

protected void FormView1_ModeChanging(object sender, FormViewModeEventArgs e)
    {
            if (e.NewMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
            {
                FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
            }
            if (e.NewMode == FormViewMode.Insert)
            {
                FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert);
            }

    }
```

I get the following error:-
FormView 'FormView1' must be in insert mode to insert a new record.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="NewButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                CommandName="New" Text="New" />
```

into your `<ItemTemplate>`.

And move your

```
<asp:LinkButton CommandName="Insert" runat="server">Insert</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

to `<InsertItemTemplate>` where it belongs to.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in `ItemCommand` event, like...

```
protected void FormView1_ItemCommand(object sender, FormViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
       if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
        {
            FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
        }
       else if (e.CommandName == "Insert")
        {
            FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CommandName` to change `FormView` to Insert mode is "New", not "Insert".  The "Insert" CommandName is to execute the actual Insert method of the datasource control when in Insert mode.

Try:

```
<asp:LinkButton CommandName="New" runat="server">New</asp:LinkButton>
```